# I need to remove folders by a specific name, if it exist

Tags: powershell

I have a file server where the users have their own diskspace. And I need to delete a certain folder on each users diskspace, but not all users have this folder. Also the users are divided into department, so the layout of the folders looks like this:

D:\users\departmentA\usernameA\foldertodelete

D:\users\departmentA\usernameB\foldertodelete

D:\users\departmentB\usernameC\foldertodelete

D:\users\departmentC\usernameD\foldertodelete

...

How can I make this happen? Im thinking of using Poweshell, and I have been reading about Test-Path, but I dont know how to work with this then the path is different for all the users.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward with PowerShell:

```
$TargetName = "foldertodelete"
$BaseDir    = "D:\Users"

# Iterate over each department directory
foreach($Department in @(Get-ChildItem $BaseDir -Directory)){
  # Within each department, iterate over each user directory
  foreach($User in @(Get-ChildItem $Department -Directory)){
    # Check if the undesirable folder exists
    if([System.IO.Directory]::Exists(($TargetPath = Join-Path -Path $User -ChildPath $TargetName))){
      # If so, remove the directory and all child items
      Remove-Item $TargetPath -Recurse
    }
  }
}
```

The `-Directory` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` is available in PowerShell 3.0 and above. For PowerShell 2.0 you could use:

```
Get-ChildItem $BaseDir |Where {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I do have some problem making the script work. It looks like the script don't understand the BaseDir part. The department folder where the users have their folder is located on D:\Users. I copied the script to C:\skript. And the error message show that it is looking for the userfolder on my C drive. It should look on D:\users\AAL-users\username

Here is the error message:

**PS C:\skript> .\RemoveFolder.ps1
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\skript\AAL-users' because it does not exist.
At C:\skript\RemoveFolder.ps1:7 char:22
+   foreach($User in @(Get-ChildItem $Department -Directory)){
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\skript\AAL-users:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemComman**d

I did try to copy the script to my D:\users folder. This time I got no error messages, but the script did not delete any folders as it is suposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below...

```
Remove-Item -path D:\Users\* -Filter *specificnameof the folder* -WhatIf --(Whatif allows you to   test a command before you run)


Remove whatif and execute the delete

Remove-Item -path C:\users\* -Filter *specificnameof the folder*
```

Comment: For your ref:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/22/the-best-way-to-use-powershell-to-delete-folders.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact code I run now:

PS D:> Remove-Item -path "D:\DU Users*" -Filter notes85
PS D:>

No error messages, but also, the folder in question is not removed.